# Elasticsearch static script in update syntax?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I can execute following update on ES 1.4.5 without issue:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/shop/product/2259/_update' -d '{
  "script" : "deleteField"
}'
```

So the script itself is fine and ES finds it ok. But if I try to do the same via PHP client I get:

```
ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: ScriptException[dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled]
```

The PHP code looks like this:

```
$updateParams = array();
$updateParams['index'] = 'shop';
$updateParams['type']  = 'product';
$updateParams['id']  = '2509';
$updateParams['body'] = array(
    'script' =>  'deleteField'
);
$es_client->update($updateParams);
```

What is the correct syntax for static scripts in PHP ES client?

N.B. I do not have to have dynamic scripting enabled as I am using static script under /config/scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is also shown when the script file is not found. So it turned out the PHP application config was changed recently and it did not connect to the correct ES instance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have dynamic scripting enabled?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_enabling_dynamic_scripting

Answer (score -1):

The error `dynamic scripting for [groovy] disabled` hints that scripting is disabled in your configuration (which is the default setting since ES 1.4.3).

Make sure you have `script.disable_dynamic: false` in your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration.